# `dir()` showing Enum element having duplicate attributes (python3.4)

Tags: python, enums

I was playing around with enums. In particular, I took this bit of code from the [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum) docs:

```
from enum import Enum
class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3
```

Then, call `dir()` on `Color.RED`:

```
In [2]: dir(Color.RED)
Out[2]: ['__class__', '__doc__', '__module__', 'name', 'name', 'value', 'value']
```

As you can see, there are two identical attributes - `name` and `value` there.

From the docs of [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir):

> *[...] With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for
>   that object.*

So why does `dir` register `Color.RED` as having identical attributes with the same name and how do they differ?

Comment: What Python version?

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry, neglected to mention that. It's in 3.4. Also, tried this out with IPython.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dir(thing)` is basically just `sorted(thing.__dir__())`, and `thing.__dir__` can return pretty much anything. Enums have a custom `__dir__` implementation that has changed a few times; in 3.4, [that `__dir__` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Lib/enum.py#L472) accidentally put `'name'` and `'value'` in the list twice, once explicitly and once from an MRO search.

Comment: I'll take this. It seems the problem is fixed with >=3.5. Wonder why no one noticed this before.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ:  Well, somebody noticed it, or I wouldn't have fixed it!  ;-)

Comment: @EthanFurman Ah! Nice to meet you. And, shame on you for letting this horrible show-stopping bug go to production :p